# The linearly is independent on extension field

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F$ and $E$ be field and $F<E$. Suppose $V$ is a vector space over $F$ with $\mathrm{dim}_F(V)=n$. Set $V^E=V\otimes_FE$(i.e. see $V$ as a vector space over $E$).

Question:

$\mathrm{dim}_E(V^E)=?$  And why?

Comment: You may want to explain some of your notation (I certainly don't know what it means) and also reread to spelling mistakes. This will make the question more comprehensible and easier to answer.

Comment: dimension over $F$, or over $E$?

Answer (score 0):

As vector spaces, $V\cong F^n$, so
$$
V^E=V\otimes_F E\cong F^n\otimes_F E\cong(F\otimes_F E)^n
$$